# Inconsistent notes placement after itemised notes in beamer

Tags: beamer, notes

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I failed to find the existing one. How can I make text of the notes in the page on the right to appear consistently with the left one?
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages} % Use notes on the 2nd screen.
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> item 1
    \note<1-> [item] {item 1}
  \item<2-> item 2
    \note<2-> [item] {item 2}
  \end{itemize}
  \visible<3->{
    Text after \texttt{itemize} environment.
  }
  \note<3->{Text after...}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter, thank you! Should I delete my then?

Comment: The usual recommendation is to promote the previous question with a bounty - but as you will loose some of the sites privileges if your rep falls below 50, I added a bounty there. Hopefully this will result in an answer, so please monitor the other question.

Comment: @samcarter, the original question has been given a satisfactory answer. Could you please mark this one as a duplicate, so people could find the solution under two different titles?